# How to protect this code from sql injection?

Tags: php, sql, code-injection

Hey all, I made a textbox which autocompletes input by getting stuff from a database and it works like this now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $("#food").autocomplete("get_course_list.php", {
        width: 260,
        cacheLength: 10,
        matchContains: false,

        //mustMatch: true,
        //minChars: 0,
        //multiple: true,
        //highlight: false,
        //multipleSeparator: ",",
        selectFirst: true

    });
});
</script>
```

and this in the .php file:

```
<?php
require_once "config2.php";
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;

$sql = "select DISTINCT voedsel as voed from voedingswaarden where voedsel LIKE '%$q%'";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $cname = $rs['voed'];
    echo "$cname\n";
}
?>
```

But now i read about sql injections etc so I wanted to protect my php script against that with mysql_real_escape_string(); but I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas how to implement this in my .php file and if this is enough protection?

Comment: `but I can't seem to get it to work.` - how did you try?

Comment: I tried something like $q = strtolower($_GET["q"]); and then $q2 = mysql_real_escape_string('$q') and than use $q2 in the rest of the code. However then the autocomplete function wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: i think you just forgot to change variable name from $q to $q2. While it was unnecessary to use invent another variable. One is enough. Anyway it's just lack of attention, not some knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
```

becomes

```
$q = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_GET["q"]));
```

your connection to the db must be established and there must be only one link, but that is the case otherwise your mysql_query wouldnt work correctly.

the code is not very elegant but it'll work.

you may want to change that:

```
if (!$q) return;
```

to

```
if (strlen($q) == 0) return;
```

Comment: thanks, this works like a charm! about the last part, is that: first it checks if there is any string at all, and the second checks of there is a string with length 0? Why exactly is the last one better? (I'm trying to learn :)) and b.t.w is this enough protection against sql injections right now?

Comment: @Javaaaa it's enough for this very code, but it will fail somewhere else.

Comment: what do you mean with somewhere else exactly?

Comment: for example if you use some wrappers for mysql or connection libraries, have multiple database connections etc.

Comment: @Javaaaa if your query goes to be `SELECT voedsel FROM voedingswaarden WHERE id  = $id` it will fail to protect

Comment: +1 thats correct. but that is another kind of design failure then :)

Answer (score 0):

I have said this before but I think `mysql_real_escape_string()` should be depecrated and you should use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) instead.

> “PDO – PHP Data Objects – is a
>   database access layer providing a
>   uniform method of access to multiple
>   databases.”

PDO is the new improved way to talk to your database. PDO has prepared statements which make your website faster/safer because:

> A prepared statement is a precompiled
>   SQL statement that can be executed
>   multiple times by sending just the
>   data to the server. It has the added
>   advantage of automatically making the
>   data used in the placeholders safe
>   from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: it cannot make your site faster though

Comment: I am (almost) certain it makes your site faster because the queries are precompiled!